# n x n matrix in numpy by applying function to pairs of elements in n x 1 numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If I have an array in numpy `a` which is `n x 1`. In addition, I have a function `F(x,y)` which takes in two values and returns a single value. I want to construct an `n x n` matrix `b` where b_ij = F(a_i, a_j) (in the array `a`). Is there any way to do this without looping over both arrays?

Comment: There is, but it's not going to be any *faster* than looping unless you change the implementation of `F` to operate naturally over entire arrays (and no, `vectorize` doesn't do that for you - it's basically just a `for` loop wrapper).

Comment: You can create a custom ufunc with `numba` to use with `outer`. How you can do this depends on your function `F`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your function is:

```
def F(a_i, a_j):
    return (a_i + a_j) if a_i % 2 == 0 else (a_i + a_j + 1)
```

To call it on 2 arrays in 1 go, define the vectorized version of
this function:

```
FF = np.vectorize(F)
```

Then call it:

```
result = FF(a, a.T)
```

As the source array I used:

```
a = np.array([[1], [5], [10], [50], [80]])
```

so its shape is *(5, 1)* (a single-column array) and got:

```
array([[  3,   7,  12,  52,  82],
       [  7,  11,  16,  56,  86],
       [ 11,  15,  20,  60,  90],
       [ 51,  55,  60, 100, 130],
       [ 81,  85,  90, 130, 160]])
```

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` is way slower than writing your functions in terms of naturally vectorized NumPy operations, though.